# Highlight Entire row if any changes occur in Range("M7:Q500") or ("C7:C500") Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, highlighting

I have set up a code but I know it's completely wrong. My goal is to highlight entire row if a change is made in ("M7:Q500") or ("C7:C500") and highlight row based on where the change was made. Ex Cell M7 (Changed) Highlight entire 7 row

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M7:Q500") Or ("C7:C500")) Is Nothing Then
    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Or` part is wrong.  Try this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M7:Q500")) Is Nothing Or _
  Not Intersect(Target, Range("C7:C500")) Is Nothing Then
    Rows(Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Comment: I'm getting a debug error on this Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

Comment: @Chrismas007 got hung up on the first error.  I totally missed the second.  Thanks.

Comment: @ScottCraner So that eliminates the debug error, but that only highlights the individual cell that is changed. How do I highlight entire row based on that change?

Comment: Did you see my edit, it should do the entire row.  @Luis The comment by Christmas007 would only do that mine should do the entire row.

Comment: @Luis please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.